# Retyping characters using getchar () and a while loop (Debugging)

Tags: c, loops, while-loop, iteration, getchar

I have a little problem with entering characters in C language. The program works fine after the first iteration of the loop, all the options from the MENU a), b), c), d), e) work. The problem, however, appears in subsequent iterations of the loop with the "a" and "c" options. It is as if it does not load characters immediately, only in the following lines. I put a link with an overview screen with the code and the console window.
Or maybe the problem is in another piece of code?
That's my fragment of code:

```
char menu(void) {
    int ch;

    printf("Enter the letter corresponding to the selected option:\n");     
    printf("  a) adding numbers to the BST tree from the keyboard \n"); 
    printf("  b) adding random numbers to the tree to determine the number of numbers \n"); 
    printf("  c) writing numbers in order from the smallest \n");
    printf("  d) removing a specific number \n");
    printf("  e) end \n");

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) 
    {
        while (getchar() != '\n')
        {
            continue;
        }
        ch = tolower(ch);                           
        if (strchr("abcde", ch) == NULL)            
            puts("Enter a, b, c, d or e:");
        else
            break;
    }
    if (ch == EOF)
        ch = 'e';
    return ch;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])    //This is main function
{
    int number, size, size_moose, element_to_delete;
    int left_compartment, right_compartment;
    char choice;
    root = NULL;


    printf("Welcome to a number sorting program that uses the BST (Binary Search Tree) sorting algorithm\n");
    printf("####################################################################################################\n");
    printf("####################################################################################################\n");
    printf("\t\tMENU\n\n");


    while ((choice = menu()) != 'e') {
        switch (choice) {
        case 'a':
            printf("How many numbers do you want to enter?\n");
            scanf("%d", &size);
            printf("Enter the numbers one after the other:\n");
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
            {
                scanf("%d", &number);
                dodawanie(number, root);  //the name of the adding function
            }
            printf("\n");
            break;
        case 'b':
            printf("How many numbers do you want to draw?\n");
            scanf("%d", &size_moose);
            printf("Enter the left boundary of the range (e.g. 1):\n");
            scanf("%d", &left_compartment);
            printf("Enter the right bound of the range (e.g. 100):\n");
            scanf("%d", &right_compartment);
            for (int i = 0; i < size_moose; i++)
            {
                 //using a random number function
                number = losowanie(left_compartment, right_compartment);  
                dodawanie(number, root);
            }
            printf("...I drew a %d number/numbers...\n", size_moose);
            printf("\n");
            break;
        case 'c':
            printf("Listing the numbers in order from the smallest:\n");
            in_order_tree_walk(root);  //a function that prints out ordered numbers
            printf("\n");
            break;
        case 'd':
            printf("Give a specific value to delete:\n");
            scanf("%d", &element_to_delete);
            kasowanie(szukaj(root, element_to_delete));  //using a function to remove a specific element
            printf("\n");
            break;
        default:
            printf("Error in switch statement\n");
        }
    }

    printf("####################################################################################################\n");
    printf("####################################################################################################\n");
    printf("Goodbye!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I put a screen with an example of the program's operation
[problemC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMAxy.png)

Comment: Our expectation is that debugging questions such as this present a [mre] demonstrating the problem directly in the question, as text.

Comment: For debugging I suggest to check the return value of *every* call to `getchar()` either by using a debugger or by printing the numeric value.